# (Discord.js) Cannot read property 'fetchMessage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have trouble with a module that I'm writing. The module should simply fetch the messages in a channel and count them. The channel name is in the config file. I have tried to reach it from the console and it works.
Here the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'calcola',
    description: 'calcola i punti',
    async execute (message, client, config) {

        console.log("inizio start counting");

        await client.channels.get(config.canaleRisposte).fetchMessages({ limit: 50 }).then(async risposte =>{
            var conuter= 0;
            risposte.forEach(risposta => {
                counter ++;
            });

        })
        console.log("end counting");

}
}
```

I'm getting this error:*(node:77497) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMessage' of undefined*

In console, I get the first console.log; so, the code works until this point. Just for reference, in my main file I got this line to get the module:

```
if (message.content === config.prefix + "calcola") client.commands.get('calcola').execute(message, client, config);
```

Thank you for your help!

PS: I have [found this website](https://qeled.github.io/discordie/#/docs/ITextChannel?p=ITextChannel%23fetchMessages&_k=u1mbtb) but I don't know how to make it work; from this website, I have added the "limit" parameter.

EDIT:
I manage to get it working, not sure how. If someone can figure it out, would be nice :D

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'calcola',
    description: 'calcola i punti',
    async execute (message, client, config) {
        console.log("inizio start counting");
        await client.channels.get(config.canaleRisposte).fetchMessages({ limit: 50 }).then(async risposte =>{
            var counter= 0;
            risposte.forEach(risposta => {
                counter ++;
            });
            console.log(counter);

        })


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the channel's `cache` to get the channel using its ID then you need to use `messages.cache` instead of `fetchMessages()`.

So your solution is:

```js
client.channels.cache.get(config.canaleRisposte).messages.cache.first(50)
```

Note `.first(50)` gets the first 50 values in a collection.

Comment: Hi Syntle, thank you for the reply,
Now I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

It looks like it cannot read the channel method. In the meanwhile, i will try to see the API documentation

Comment: Are you running discord.js v11 or v12?

Comment: Im running "discord.js": "^11.4.2",

Comment: Okay so your original code was right, what's the value of `config.canaleRisposte`? Did you store it as a string or a number?

Comment: Ok, I got this working using:
await client.channels.get(config.canaleRisposte).fetchMessages({ limit: 50 })
There was a mistake in the code: I misspelled counter (var conuter= 0;).
Could have been that 'causing the error?

EDIT: no, that was not causing the issue. I will post my working code inside the answer.

Comment: That's weird, that's the same as the original code in the question, what did you change?

Comment: I corrected the counter name (wrong name still in the original question).
Another thing I did was to run the command outside the config.canaleRisposte and it was working. Then I run the code inside the same channel as config.canaleRisposte and it was still working.

Comment: So, in another module I have a similar line: client.channels.get(config.canaleRisposte).send(`${message.author.id} ${risposta} ${message.author.username}`); 
Yesterday was working, but today is throwing the same error as per question. So I think I have touched something in the main file maybe? I will keep on looking for the solution of this mystery :D

Comment: So, I think I find out where the problem is.
async execute (message, client, config) {
Here, message is not used inside the module. If I run the code like this, it will give me error. If I delete message or move it after config, it will work. 
Now, I dont know if this is how it should be or not as I have just start discord.js and this could be basic implementation...